# how to get values from jsp

Tags: java, jsp

In my jsp am using file upload in  the form of enctype="multipart/form-data" and get the form values in another jsp. am getting null value . plz...any one tell any solution....thanks in advance..
hear is my jsp coding

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form name="corporateProfile" method="POST"
 onsubmit="return checkTheFields();" action="editUpdate.jsp"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
  <tr>
      <td class="bgcolor" align="right" valign="top" style="padding:3px">
          <b>Upload Customer Logo</b></td>
      <td colspan="3" class="bgcolor" align="left" valign="top"
           style="padding:3px">
          <input TYPE="file" VALUE="Browse" NAME="uploadCustomerLogo"
           maxlength="1000" size="40" class="controlStyle" tabindex="17">
      </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="40"
           class="controlStyle" maxlength="256" tabindex="11">
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</form>
</html>
```

editUpdate.jsp

```
<%
String params  = request.getParamater("email");
out.println(params);
%>
```

output gives

```
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an **id** to the `< form >` tag

```
<form name="corporateProfile" id="corporateProfile"
```

and then try `request.getParamater("email");`

Answer (score 1):

`getParameter` on a multipart form will return null.
There are 4 solutions listed [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1045507).